# How to use Facebook OAuth 2.0 authentication like Zynga and other use it?

Tags: redirect, oauth, facebook

I want to display the "Request for Permission" box directly when the user enters http://apps.facebook.com/myfancyapp. The [Facebook Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation is pretty clear on how the URL have to look like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[APPID]&redirect_uri=http://www.myfancyapp.com/&scope=user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream
```

Pasting this URL directly into the browser works like it should. What I want is to redirect the user via JavaScript (or something else) from the application URL

```
http://apps.facebook.com/myfancyapp
```

to the authentication box URL above.

I thought something like this would work:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
      window.location = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[APPID]&redirect_uri=http://www.myfancyapp.com/&scope=user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream"
   //-->
   </script>
```

This redirects me to a page with a body that looks like this

[image: Facebook]

Clicking on the image/test then redirects to the authentication box.

How can I directly redirect to the "Request for Permission" box. I know it works somehow as other developers (Zynga for example) already do it.

Comment: Would that be a canvas app or a stand-alone website that implements facebook connect? What scripting language? PHP/Javascript?

Comment: It's a canvas app and I'm using PHP and JavaScript. When I use the redirect from outside of Facebook it works though. I guess the window.location is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm doing the same thing as the asker, only instead of window.location, use top.location.href = "https://graph....."

Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[APPID]&scope=email&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/myfancyapp/";
</script>
```

Prompts for login if needed, and then permissions.  Then redirects to the app.

Comment: I get this error when i try this:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

Comment: @ria if this happens when you're running the app locally, it simply means you need to create a new app on facebook that points to your localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with PHP is a cinch.

On the backend

```
$facebook = new Facebook( array(
    'appId'  => '<FB_APP_ID>'
  , 'secret' => '<FB_APP_SECRET>'
  , 'cookie' => true
));

$fbSession = $facebook->getSession();
if ( !$fbSession )
{
  $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
      'canvas'     => 1
    , 'fbconnect'  => 0
    , 'display'    => 'page'
    , 'cancel_url' => null
    , 'req_perms'  => 'user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream'
  ) );
}
```

And then, on the frontend

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  top.location.href = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
</script>
<p>
Not being redirected? <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_top">Click Here.</a>
</p>
```